# require msg.value depending on different cases

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

My case is I have item free mint functionality like if sender have 3 item free mint and trying to mint 5 item i want to ask sender to pay only for 2 items.

it doesnot works and I think error is here:

```
int256 payableMints = int256(_mintAmount - freeMints);

   if(payableMints < 0){
       payableMints = 0;
   }
   
   if(payableMints > 0){
       require(msg.value >= (cost * uint256(payableMints)));
   }
   else{
       require(msg.value >= (freeMintCost * _mintAmount));
   }
```

am i doing something  wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the type of `freeMintCost` but if it is a `uint256` type, for example, you need to convert `_mintAmount` to uint256:

```
 require(msg.value >= (freeMintCost * uint256(_mintAmount)));
```

I tested this code and worked:

```
contract Test {

   int256 freeMints = 3;
   uint256 cost = 1000;
   uint256 freeMintCost = 0;
    
   function mint(int256 _mintAmount) public payable {
       int256 payableMints = int256(_mintAmount - freeMints);
       if(payableMints < 0){
        payableMints = 0;
       }
       if(payableMints > 0){
        require(msg.value >= (cost * uint256(payableMints)));
       }
       else{
        require(msg.value >= (freeMintCost * uint256(_mintAmount)));
       }
   }
}
```